# CvSize does not exist?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have installed the official python bindings for OpenCv and I am implementing some standard textbook functions just to get used to the python syntax.  I have run into the problem, however, that CvSize does not actually exist, even though it is documented on the site...

The simple function: `blah = cv.CvSize(inp.width/2, inp.height/2)` yields the error `'module' object has no attribute 'CvSize'`.  I have imported with 'import cv'.

Is there an equivalent structure?  Do I need something more?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that they opted to eventually avoid this structure altogether. Instead, it just uses a python tuple (width, height).

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit more to Nathan Keller's answer, in later versions of OpenCV some basic structures are simply implemented as Python Tuples.

For example in OpenCV 2.4:

This (incorrect which will give an error)

```
image = cv.LoadImage(sys.argv[1]);
grayscale = cv.CreateImage(cvSize(image.width, image.height), 8, 1)
```

Would instead be written as this

```
image = cv.LoadImage(sys.argv[1]);
grayscale = cv.CreateImage((image.width, image.height), 8, 1)
```

Note how we just pass the Tuple directly.

Answer (score 0):

The right call is cv.cvSize(inp.width/2, inp.height/2).

All functions in the python opencv bindings start with a lowercased c even in the highgui module.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the documentation is wrong and you have to use `cv.cvSize` instead of `cv.CvSize` ?
Also, do a dir(cv) to find out the methods available to you.

Comment: Tried all of those.  Got the solution, though.  It seems that they opted to eventually avoid this structure altogether.  Instead, it just uses a python tuple (width, height).

Comment: @socks Other simple structures like CvRect and CvScalar are also implemented with tuples in Python.

Comment: @socks - you should write your solution as an answer, it just helped me. Upvoted your question anyway... :)